# JTable doesn't add header row

Tags: java, swing, jtree, header-row

I try to add header row to my `JTable` and next put table on panel.
This is my  sample code :

```
Map <String, Float> tmpCart = new HashMap<String , Float>();
    MainPanel.removeAll();
    MainPanel.repaint();
    tmpCart = cart.GetMap();
        DefaultTableModel tab = new DefaultTableModel();
        tab.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Name", "Price"});
            for (String key : tmpCart.keySet())
            tab.addRow(new Object[] {key, tmpCart.get(key)});
        JTable jTab = new JTable(tab);
        jTab.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);
        jTab.setBackground(Color.orange);
        jTab.setRowHeight(25);
        JScrollPane pan =new JScrollPane(jTab);
         MainPanel.add(pan);
        // MainPanel.add(jTab);
       // pan.repaint();
```

How do I write it properly?

//answer

I try create `JTable` dynamically, after push button, I want get data from `Hashtable`, create table and put this table on panel.

First step is remove all components from panel, and next create `JTable` using data from Hashmap`

full function:

```
private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
Map <String, Float> tmpCart = new HashMap<String , Float>();
MainPanel.removeAll();
MainPanel.repaint();
tmpCart = cart.GetMap();
    DefaultTableModel tab = new DefaultTableModel();
    tab.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Name", "Price"});
        for (String key : tmpCart.keySet())
        tab.addRow(new Object[] {key, tmpCart.get(key)});
    JTable jTab = new JTable(tab);
    jTab.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);
    jTab.setBackground(Color.orange);
    jTab.setRowHeight(25);

    // MainPanel.add(pan);
     MainPanel.add(jTab);
```

}

This code works,  create table and put it  on panel,  but  doesn't set  first  row with  column names   ( text : "Names" and "Price").

Comment: please change your `JTree doesn't add header` row to the `JTable doesn't add header row` or to the `JTreeTable doesn't add header row`

Comment: You still haven't posted an SSCCE!

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: never-ever call setBounds in application code - instead use a layoutManager

Answer (score 3):

Can't tell exactly what you are doing from the code sample.

If you are trying to dynamically update a table on a visible GUI, then there is not need to create a new table, just reset the TableModel.

```
table.setModel( model );
```

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Edit:

> First step is remove all components from panel,

Why are your removing components from the panel?

If you need to "swap" panels, then use a CardLayout.

If you need to "refresh" existing components, then just reset the model as explained above.

```
// MainPanel.add(pan);
MainPanel.add(jTab);
```

The scrollPane should be added to the GUI, not the table.

Answer (score 2):

The table header is another component that only gets added automatically when the table is inside a JScrollPane. Your best bet is to create a JScrollPane via

```
new JScrollPane(table)
```

and add that to your MainPanel.

The other option is to added the header directly wherever you want it, and for that you can do:

```
panel.add(table.getTableHeader())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it into a JScrollPane.